# How to exclude attributes from nested model in sequelize?

Tags: typescript, database, sequelize.js

I have 2 models `User` and `Role`. Those 2 models have `many-to-many` connections. So, I created third model - `UserRole`.

And here is the problem, in this query this `UserRole` is also included.

```
async getUser(conditionals: object) {
  return await this.userRepository.findOne({
    where: { ...conditionals },
    include: [{ model: Role, attributes: 'value' } ]
  });
}
```

Example of response (don't pay attention to format, the data was coded and decoded from `jwt`):

```
{
  "userId": "7a145aea-72c8-4b96-a25b-b404f9b1bf5a",
  "username": "bl4drnnr",
  "roles": [
    {
      "value": "USER",
      "UserRole": {
        "id": "e9d2afe8-ddd1-4311-ab14-6638b79d0d80",
        "userId": "7a145aea-72c8-4b96-a25b-b404f9b1bf5a",
        "roleId": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001"
      }
    }
  ],
  "type": "access",
  "iat": 1659878703,
  "exp": 1659879603
}
```

As you already got, what I want to do is to exclude this `UserRole` model and make it look like this:

```
{
  "userId": "7a145aea-72c8-4b96-a25b-b404f9b1bf5a",
  "username": "bl4drnnr",
  "roles": [ { "value": "USER" } ],
  "type": "access",
  "iat": 1659878703,
  "exp": 1659879603
}
```

I was trying to use `exclude` as sequelize property, but it seems to be working only with fields, not models. So, how can I exclude this `UserRole` model from database request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using `through` with empty array of `attributes`:

```
async getUser(conditionals: object) {
  return await this.userRepository.findOne({
    where: { ...conditionals },
    include: [
        {
          model: Role,
          attributes: ['value'],
          through: {
            attributes: []
          }
        }
      ]
  });
}
```

Comment: BTW, if this solves your question, please consider upvoting it.